# Is it okay to create an anchor for every object in sceneform?

Tags: android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform, android-augmented-reality

I am making an app where I would have to display a lot of objects and they need to stay where they are initialized. I started by creating an anchor and making all the objects as Node that are going to be children of that anchor.

This works if the objects are not to far away but, if you move quite a bit away, the anchor and, as a result, the children of that anchor also start drifting. To combat this issue I decided to establish each object as an anchor instead of a node that will then be a child of one anchor.

However, now my app is lagging a lot. Is creating too many anchors causing this?

Answer (score 0):

if you make them nodes connected to one parent node they will always drift. It's ok to create multiple anchors in this way they will stay where the user has created a hit and will not drift